# Every time I Open my laptop I am getting this dialog-box. Why that appears?

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

```
 C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience_1.100.2765.0_x64_8j3eqge...

Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience_1.100.2765.0_x64_8j3eq..\IGCCTray.exe'
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

Why I am getting this?

[dialoge box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWtgI.png)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error (only difference that the .2765. was now .4232., probably a newer version).

But, the other administrator account on the machine didn't get the error. I opened the Intel Graphics Command Center on that other account, and had to accept a user licence there. That didn't fix the problem however.

Then I noticed that one setting was different on the different accounts, **the unaffected account had Update Notifications turned off** in the Intel Graphics Command Center, I turned it on and now everything seems to work on both accounts.

I would think, that one or both of these things had something to do with fixing the problem, but cannot be sure...

---

Intel also has [an article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056552/graphics.html) about this error, they recommend a reinstall of the Intel Graphics Control Panel or Intel Graphics Command Center. I did not try that because it worked on the other account.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling/updating the driver of your Intel integrated graphics and its components. My First approach would be to (re-)install Intel Graphics Command Center, second approach would
Intel Graphics Control Panel.

(the lazy way would be to just remove the autorun entry)

Answer (score 0):

You get this message because somewhere on your system the igcctray.exe application (**I**ntel **G**raphics **C**ontrol **C**enter) is set to auto-start when you log into Windows, and the application apparently does not exist, or at least not in the specified folder.

If you want to fix this, you could follow the suggestions by @dsfsdfdsf and try the [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) tool to delete the entry, or [reinstall](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/igcctrayexe-error-message-of-intel-graphic-driver/378c4879-25d7-428e-9c0c-18aae155ddc3) the Intel software.